# Understanding xsl:copy with xsl:apply-templates (XSLT 2.0)

Tags: xml, xslt

What is the difference between the following three templates?

```
<xsl:template match="food">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="food">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="food">
<xsl:copy>
</xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

My guess would be that the first and the second are the same. But what about the third one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="food">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

copies a `food` element, then applies templates to that element's child nodes (child elements, comments and text nodes), placing the results inside the copied element.  It does *not* do anything to any attributes that the original `food` element had.

```
<xsl:template match="food">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As above, but applies templates to the `food` element's attributes as well as its children.  Whether this has any observable effect depends whether there are any templates that match these attribute nodes and what those templates do.  If you have a general identity template (see below) then the copied `food` element would end up with the same attributes as the original one.

```
<xsl:template match="food">
<xsl:copy>
</xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

as in the first case, but places the result of applying templates to the children *after* the (empty) copied `food` element rather than inside it.

Generally you would expect to see templates of this kind alongside a general "identity" template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

that copies everything unchanged except where more specific templates override this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

> My guess would be that the first and the second are the same.

No they are not the same. The first one does not apply templates to attributes. These two are the same:

```
<xsl:apply-templates>

<xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
```

> But what about the third one?

The third one applies templates outside of the copied node, resulting in flattening the hierarchy: children will become siblings.